# A cardinal comes home

Tags: pattern, knowledge

After coming home he ate all the food in the house, 
He didn't want to share any of it with his wife, 
Then he noticed his neighbor's got way more food than him, 
So he went and beat the neighbor, 
Then he returned home and had sex with his wife, 
And finally went to sleep, having done no chores. 
 
And when the cardinal woke up, he felt very

Comment: Hope this is my last 'pattern' puzzle

Comment: You hope? Well, I don't :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks to me like

> the traditional Seven Deadly Sins

so on the basis of the missing one I think that when he awoke he felt very

> proud.

*After coming home he ate all the food in the house,*

> Gluttony.

*He didn't want to share any of it with his wife,*

> Avarice.

*Then he noticed his neighbor's got way more food than him,*

> Envy.

*So he went and beat the neighbor,*

> Anger.

*Then he returned home and had sex with his wife,*

> Lust.

*And finally went to sleep, having done no chores.*

> Sloth.

(I might quibble about a couple of the definitions.)

Incidentally, I suspect that the cardinal may have been

> [this chap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Sin). Traditionally one has cardinal *virtues*, of course, rather than cardinal *sins*.

Comment: rot13(Rirelguvat vf pbeerpg. V ersreerq gb Jvxvcrqvn sbe "pneqvany fva" rkcerffvba, gubhtu, ohg lbhe nqqvgvba bs n cebcre pneqvany vf irel avpr vaqrrq.)

Comment: Also you might have a slightly bigger chance to solve my another pattern-puzzle now.

Comment: You may replace "x deadly" with "cardinal".

Comment: I may, but these objects (unlike their opposites) are much more often referred to as "deadly" than as "cardinal".

Comment: Interesting that the reference is by name, not action